# How to fetch data from WSDL in C#?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I need to consume a service endpoint which is WSDL.

I tried adding it as a webreference and service reference. In both occasions I couldn't find an effective method to fetch data.

Below is the service consumed in SoapUI -

[image: SoapUI Request and Response]

[image]

Comment: did you create client ?

Comment: You probably have a client somehwere in that list. You want to find that `client.GetAlWrPersonBySearchInput`

Comment: @DiskJunky I guess what's needed is a client to send the _request_ to which gives a filled _response_ object back, instead of one having to fill in th eresponse by themselves, making the whole service obsolete :)

Answer (score 0):

When you added ServiceReference, it would have created a Client\Proxy Class as well. This client in actual serializes the data into soap format, sends it over the network and then deserializes the soap response into memory response objects which you can consume

Answer (score 0):

when you do a "Add Service Reference", on the dialog that comes up, click on the [Advanced] button in the button left corner and on the next dialog that comes up, pick the [Add Web Reference] button at the bottom.
[image]

Notice that there is a namespace, have you included that namespace in the class that is calling the web service

That namespace should contain a client class that will allow you to invoke the web service

Answer (score 0):

I could consume this service by creating the client object and calling the method from client.